# preg_replace /e deprecated solution for replacement calling a method with multiple argument

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

our old code base is using something like below:

```
$x = $this->$getParsing();
$c = preg_replace('|site://([\w\-]+?)/([\w\-]+?)/([\w\-\/\.]+)?|e','$x->getList(\'$1\', \'$2\', \'$3\')',$c);

print_r($c);
```

Comment: if I understand your statement... check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: @NMoeini No, this is not a duplicate.  `preg_replace_callback` takes one match at a time.  The OP was using /e option to deal with a callback taking **multiple** matches as multiple arguments.  `preg_replace_callback` cannot take multiple arguments.

Comment: @Aleks G, are you positive? You can pass all matches as an array to the function callback and also pass multiple arguments to use.

Comment: It is a duplicate as the answer explains how to pass a variable to the callback function.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OP doesn't need to pass a variable, he needs to pass more than one match into the same function.

Comment: @josheph j, as this has been closed as duplicate I post here a direct answer. Test it. `$c = preg_replace_callback('|site://([\w\-]+?)/([\w\-]+?)/([\w\-\/\.]+)?|', function($m) use ($x) { return $x->getList($m[1], $m[2], $m[3]);} ,$c);`

Comment: Of course, and it is perfectly in line with the duplicate status of the question.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions.